# ListView included in custom control

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I am creating some more complex controls containing already defined controls for use in my application which I am currently working.

I have an issue with a ListView control on which I try to "draw" a table (View = Details). I add the columns header for my ListView and a couple of rows. The header and the rows are visible in the designer from my custom activity, but when I add the custom control on a Windows form I cannot see them neither on the designer, neither when executing the application. The custom activity contains also other predefined controls: ListBox, TextBox, etc, which are shown correctly, but the ListView isn't and I cannot find any reasonable explanation for this. I made also some debug and observed that the items are there but simply are not shown in the form.

Someone have any idea how I can go over this issue? :)

Comment: show some code please. I have bad imagination to create exact image on my mind of your control and problem :)

Comment: Check the Visible property of the ListView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, for trying to help me with this.

I manged to solve the problem in not a very elegant manner, but one that it works. I will add my solution if anyone would need help with a similar problem.

I don't know if it could be understand from my question but I created the custom control from the designer. It seems that there is a small bug with generating the Designer file if adding a ListView on a custom control. For some reason the columns added in the designer are not added into the *.Designer file, I manually added them and the problem was solved. The lines of code that should be added in this case will be something like this:

```
this.myListView.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader[] {
        this.myColumnHeader1,
        this.myColumnHeader2,
        this.myColumnHeader3});

        // 
        // myColumnHeader1
        // 
        this.myColumnHeader1.Text = "My Column Header1";
        this.myColumnHeader1.Width = 100;
        // 
        // myColumnHeader2
        // 
        this.myColumnHeader2.Text = "My Column Header 2";
        this.myColumnHeader2.Width = 100;
        // 
        // myColumnHeader3
        // 
        this.myColumnHeader3.Text = "My Column Header 3";
        this.myColumnHeader3.Width = 100;
```

I must also note that this problem can be observed only when adding the ListView through the designer on a custom control, if it is added directly on a Windows form the *.Designer file will be saved Ok.

Answer (score 0):

call BringToFront(); method of list view

or in design time do this from contextmenu (rightclick on control and select these items)

or set top and left of list view in code to visible area